# Number of convex polyhedra whose faces are regular polygons and whose largest face is an $n$-gon

Tags: recreational-mathematics, polyhedra, combinatorial-geometry, oeis

I'm trying to count up the number of convex polyhedra whose faces are regular polygons and whose largest face is an $n$-gon. (I.e. either a [uniform polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_polyhedron) or a [Johnson solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Johnson_solids).) If I've done my counting correct, this [does not appear](https://oeis.org/search?q=8%2C30%2C_%2C_%2C_%2C_%2C_%2C_%2C_%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2) in the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, and I'd like to add it.

Are my lists complete and correct?

---

#### For $n = 3$, I've counted $8$:

Tetrahedron,
octahedron,
icosahedron,
[$J_{12}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_bipyramid),
[$J_{13}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_bipyramid),
[$J_{17}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroelongated_square_bipyramid), [$J_{51}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triaugmented_triangular_prism),
[$J_{84}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_disphenoid).

#### For $n=4$, I've counted $30$:

Cube,
cuboctahedron,
rhombicuboctahedron,
snub cube,
triangular prism,
square antiprism,
$J_{1}$,
$J_{7}$,
$J_{8}$,
$J_{10}$,
$J_{14}$,
$J_{15}$,
$J_{16}$,
$J_{26}$,
$J_{27}$,
$J_{28}$,
$J_{29}$,
$J_{35}$,
$J_{36}$,
$J_{37}$,
$J_{44}$,
$J_{45}$,
$J_{49}$,
$J_{50}$,
$J_{85}$,
$J_{86}$,
$J_{87}$,
$J_{88}$,
$J_{89}$,
$J_{90}$.

#### For $n = 5$, I've counted $37$:

Dodecahedron,
icosidodecahedron,
rhombicosidodecahedron,
snub dodecahedron,
pentagonal prism,
pentagonal antiprism,
$J_{2}$,
$J_{9}$,
$J_{11}$,
$J_{30}$,
$J_{31}$,
$J_{38}$,
$J_{39}$,
$J_{46}$,
$J_{52}$,
$J_{53}$,
$J_{62}$,
$J_{63}$,
$J_{64}$,
$J_{91}$,
$J_{32}$,
$J_{33}$,
$J_{40}$,
$J_{41}$,
$J_{47}$,
$J_{61}$,
$J_{59}$,
$J_{60}$,
$J_{58}$,
$J_{34}$,
$J_{42}$,
$J_{43}$,
$J_{48}$,
$J_{72}$,
$J_{73}$,
$J_{74}$,
$J_{75}$.

#### For $n = 6$, I've counted $14$:

Truncated tetrahedron,
truncated octahedron,
truncated icosahedron,
hexagonal prism,
hexagonal antiprism,
$J_{3}$,
$J_{18}$,
$J_{22}$,
$J_{54}$,
$J_{55}$,
$J_{56}$,
$J_{57}$,
$J_{65}$,
$J_{92}$.

#### For $n = 7$, I've counted $2$:

Heptagonal prism,
heptagonal antiprism.

#### For $n = 8$, I've counted $9$:

Truncated cube,
truncated cuboctahedron,
octagonal prism,
octagonal antiprism,
$J_{4}$,
$J_{19}$,
$J_{23}$,
$J_{66}$,
$J_{67}$.

#### For $n = 9$, I've counted $2$:

Enneagonal prism,
enneagonal antiprism.

#### For $n = 10$, I've counted $22$:

Truncated dodecahedron,
truncated icosidodecahedron,
decagonal prism,
decagonal antiprism,
$J_{5}$,
$J_{6}$,
$J_{20}$,
$J_{21}$,
$J_{24}$,
$J_{25}$,
$J_{68}$,
$J_{69}$,
$J_{70}$,
$J_{71}$,
$J_{76}$,
$J_{77}$,
$J_{78}$,
$J_{79}$,
$J_{80}$,
$J_{81}$,
$J_{82}$,
$J_{83}$.

#### For $n > 10$, I've counted $2$:

$n$-gonal prism, $n$-gonal antiprism.

Comment: Actually. I gave this q a +1 for using "enneagon" for the nine-sided figure, maintaining the Greek numbering.  I think there may be at least one more for both the enneagon and the dodecagon, but I have to recheck to make sure.

Comment: I didn't use the name to be pedantic—I was just trying to be consistent with Wikipedia's conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out your list is complete.  Having recognized the five Platonic and 13 Archimedean solids by the names you list, I turn to the [Johnson solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_solid), which are defined as all other strictly convex (dihedral angles all <180°) polyhedra consisting of regular faces besides prisms and antiprisms.  Norman Johnson identified 92 solids, all of which are in your list, in 1966; the numbering we use today is from his identification.  That the 92 solids so identified is the complete list of Johnson solids was proved by Victor Zalgaller in 1969.

I also checked your count of the Johnson solids for each individual value of $n$ in your lists.  These too are correct.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

After Oscar posted his confirmation, I triple-checked with the following Mathematica program and was able to have the computer confirm it too.

```
MaxFace[l_] := Max[Length /@ l];
a[n_] := Count[
  Join[
    MaxFace /@ PolyhedronData["Platonic", "FaceIndices"],
    MaxFace /@ PolyhedronData["Archimedean", "FaceIndices"],
    MaxFace /@ PolyhedronData["Johnson", "FaceIndices"],
    Range[4, n], (*Prisms, including triangular prism, excluding cube*)
    Range[4, n]  (*Antiprisms, excluding octahedron*)
  ],
  n
]
```